# Jquery remove() only skips select options, rather than deleting them

Tags: javascript, jquery

Am trying to delete/remove/disable the `options` of a `select` on click of a span. I am trying to remove only those options whose values are lower than the current time (values are total minutes, I find current time and convert to total minutes, before comparing.)

HTML:

```
<span class="flatpickr-day today">22</span>

<div class="mvvwb_sel_wrap">
  <select name="mvvwb_timeStart">
    <option value="540">09:00</option>
    <option value="600">10:00</option>
    <option value="660">11:00</option>
    <option value="720">12:00</option>
    <option value="780">13:00</option>
    <option value="840">14:00</option>
    <option value="900">15:00</option>
    <option value="960">16:00</option>
    <option value="1020">17:00</option>
    <option value="1080">18:00</option>
    <option value="1140">19:00</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.flatpickr-day.today').click(function () {
  var time = new Date();
  var currentTime = time.toLocaleString('en-US', { hour: 'numeric', hour12: false });
  var currentTimeMinutes = currentTime*60;
  $(".mvvwb_sel_wrap select > option").each(function() {
    var optionTime = parseInt(this.value);
    if(optionTime < currentTimeMinutes) {
      this.remove();
    }
  });
});
```

The 3 other ways that I tried that flat out didn't work:

```
this.prop('disabled',true);
this.attr('disabled','disabled');
this.css('display','none');
```

Comment: It's working... WHen click on time here 22*60=900 if get only time from 15:00 to end

Comment: `this` in the `each` function, as well as other similar functions, is the node element. To use jQuery functions on it, you need to wrap it `$(this)`.

Comment: @Gil I tried that but it didn't solve the issue, in fact, it wouldn't even skip anymore.

Comment: It works for me too. Are there errors in the console?